# WCF Endpoints fail after restarting the service

Tags: wcf, web-services, crud

I'm new working with WCF and so far I understand the basic to create a web service with it, but I have a problem with some of my methods.

I have my services defined as follows **[link](http://pastebin.com/3U1dgZWC)** and my web.config is like **[this](http://pastebin.com/dTnNJDj6)**. My model has 5 entities, one of them is not related to the rest for the moment, the other four are related among them, my model looks like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/466mb.png). I have endpoints that do the usual CRUD operations, there's no problem inserting, updating or deleting, but when I tried to get the list of Eventos, Regiones, Clusters and Dispositivos, the method fail and doesn't return anything.

The funny part is that if I generate the database from my model again, restart the service and reinsert the data again, I can get the data from the endpoints with no problem. But if I stop the service and restart it againg, then it fails once again.

This only happens with the four entities that are related, all the endpoints for Usuarios work fine, but for the other 4, the endpoints fail only when I'm trying to retrieve all of the entries or just one entry of an entity. If I try to insert, update or delete an entry from any of these entities there's no problem, the problem is only present when I try to get the list of entries or just one entry.

For example if I try to access the url **127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/region/index** it returns in Google Chrome Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE), but that doesn't happen with **127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/usuario/index**, that url return me the correct JSON object I'm expecting which looks like this:

{"Meta":{"Method":"GetUsuarios","Status":"ok"},"Response":[{"ApellidoM":"Mendoza","ApellidoP":"Arvizu","CreatedDateTime":"/Date(1357947261710-0600)/","Nombre":"Uriel","Password":"uriel88","UpdatedDateTime":"/Date(1357947261710-0600)/","UserName":"uriel88","UsuarioId":1},{"ApellidoM":"Mendoza2","ApellidoP":"Arvizu2","CreatedDateTime":"/Date(1357947273070-0600)/","Nombre":"Uriel2","Password":"auam","UpdatedDateTime":"/Date(1357947273070-0600)/","UserName":"auam","UsuarioId":2}]}

Why are these endpoints failing?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by trying to send objects with circular referencing, since EF creates the objects for a determined entity, if for example you want to send an object *foo* of type EntityA, which has a property of type EntityB, that property will have a property of type EntityA that references the original object *foo*, this creates a circular reference which can not be parsed into JSON by the service.

What I did was the following: To create a new instance of type EntityA and assign to each of its properties the values you're interested from the *foo* object, leaving the objects that creates a circular reference as null.